# how 2D array pass as object in MPJ

Tags: java, mpi, mpj-express

I am trying to pass 2d array as object in MPJ library but it gives error at this line

```
Object sendobject = new Object[1];
sendobject[0] = (Object)g.adjMatrix;  
//Graph g = new Graph();
// adjmatrix is public member of class Graph having detail of 
// connecting nodes to each other
```

Im currently follow the example of [this blog](http://mpjexpress.blogspot.com/search?updated-min=2009-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&updated-max=2010-01-01T00:00:00-08:00&max-results=6).

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: aaray required  but java.lang.object found

Comment: What is the type of `g.adjMatrix`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, why you create an array with one element, but this:

```
Object sendobject = new Object[1];
```

does not work.
Either you want an array:

```
Object[] sendobject = new Object[1];
```

or you want only one `Object`

```
Object sendobject = (Object)g.adjMatrix;
```

Comment: adjmatix  is 2d array and member of graph class

Comment: @Mohsan Naqi: why do want to store it in an Object reference and not in a reference of its real type?

Comment: i want to divide the matrix and send it on different processors to solve it parallel  . Currently MPJ does not support direct pass 2d array